# AdventureWorks in SQL Server 2019 : ordershare percent for each item per month

Tags: sql-server, group-by, common-table-expression, adventureworks

I'm new to SQL Server. I'm trying to write a code to find the sale percent/per item/per month. Something like this:

| Year | Month | ProductID | Order_Quantity_Per_Month | Total_Sold_Per_Month | %_Of_Total_Sale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | 5 | 707 | 422 | 17024 | 2 |

1. First and most importantly, I want to write this code with "CTE" and "Group by". I've tried many times but I failed. How can I write this code with cte and group by?
2. I wrote this code with "Over" and "Partition". Could someone check the codes I've written to see if it's actually correct:

   ```sql
   USE AdventureWorks2019
   GO

   SELECT
       YEAR (soh.OrderDate) As Year,
       MONTH (soh.OrderDate) As Month,
       pro.productid AS [Product ID],
       pro.Name AS [Product Name],
       SUM(sod.OrderQty) OVER (PARTITION BY Month(soh.OrderDate) ORDER BY by soh.OrderDate) AS [Order Quantity Per Month],
       SUM(sod.OrderQty) OVER (PARTITION BY Month(soh.OrderDate)) AS [Total Sold Per Month],
       SUM(sod.OrderQty) OVER (PARTITION BY Month(soh.OrderDate) ORDER BY by soh.OrderDate) * 100 / SUM(sod.OrderQty) OVER (PARTITION BY Month(soh.OrderDate)) AS [% of TotalSale]
   FROM      
       Production.Product pro
   INNER JOIN  
       Sales.SalesOrderdetail sod ON pro.ProductID = sod.ProductID
   INNER JOIN  
       Sales.SalesOrderheader soh ON soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
   GROUP BY
       YEAR(soh.OrderDate), MONTH(soh.OrderDate),
       soh.OrderDate, pro.productid, pro.Name, sod.OrderQty
   ORDER BY 
       Year, Month
   ```

If the above code is correct, How can I write the code with cte and group by?

Comment: Your query doesn't appear to be correct: The grouping includes `YEAR(soh.OrderDate), MONTH(soh.OrderDate), soh.OrderDate` which doesn't make sense, as each date will be grouped separately anyway, you probably wanted just the month, so you could use only the first two. You are also grouping by `sod.OrderQty` which is probably unintended. Then the sums are probably wrong also: `Order Quantity Per Month` is actually calculating a *running* sum by date, partitioned by month (but not year), .....

Comment: .... `Total Sold Per Month` is calculating a windowed sum by month (but not year) and the percent is using integer division rather than decimal

Answer (score 0):

I think the better question is why you want (or need) to use a CTE. A simple CTE (i.e., not recursive) is just syntactic sugar for a derived table. There is nothing particular special or complicated about writing and using one in a query. If you "tried many times", you should have included those attempts in your question.

But to satisfy the need to use a CTE, you can simply "cram" the query you have into the CTE and select rows from it. Example:

```
with cteOrders as (
    select ... -- your original query here without ORDER BY clause
)
select * from cteOrders 
order by [Year], [Month]
;
```

That is a extremely simplistic way of using a CTE. There is no real or obvious advantage to doing so but it does satisfy your goal. Because of that, I smell a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The reason that I'm trying to use "CTE" and "Group by" instead of "Over" and "Partition By" is just for practice. I'm new to SQL and for a reason my attempts to solve this by "Group by" wasn't successful. So first I want to know if my above code is correct and then what's the best way to solve this query simply by using "Group by" :)

Comment: Not many people will test your code and determine if it is correct - especially without a clear definition of your goal. I find your formulas suspicious just by glancing at them. Do you have multiple years of data? Think carefully about what "partition by month" means in that case. And I tend to avoid "best" questions because "best" cannot be measured and is dependent on skills, restrictions, and environment. Browsing this site will find many examples (good and bad) of CTE usage - no better way to learn IMO.

Comment: Apologies if I was not clear enough to ask my question. I just want to mention that I've searched and read solutions of similar questions on net and stack overflow and that's how I wrote the above code.
1- I want to calculate the percent of item sold for each month. for example: 
"A" total items = 10
total of item "A" sold in January 2012 =  2
total of item "A" sold in January 2012 = %2
and list goes on for each month to the end of the list that's why I included year and month in formula.
2- I want to write this code with "Group by". I don't claim there is an advantage in it :)

Comment: And in terms of people will not test my code, I've seen many people asked many questions here on Stackoverflow which were even similar in context. Other people corrected their formula and assisted them. I don't think it's a complicated code for advance people or it's gonna take a long time for them to understand it. It's just a three line of a simple formula. even if no one likes my code, if they could give me a new code so I could have a reference to check it against my code and find a better solution, I'll appreciate it.